# Moving from VSS to SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I need to write a script to make a source safe project ready to be moved to subversion, what do I need to do so far I can think of:

- remove .scc files
- remove .vspcc files

Do I need to remove the "read-only" attribute of all the files as well, or will that not matter?

What language would you write this script in, I was planning to do it in python (os.walk is great), but maybe powershell would be more appropriate to chnage file attributes on windows (if I need to)?

Is there anything else you can think of that needs to be done before I move the project to SVN?

Comment: Are you just adding the project files to a new blank SVN repo, or migrating all the history across?

Comment: Just a fresh svn repo...were going to keep the old versions in source safe...

Answer (score 8):

For a manual migration (or to understand what happens) :

- remove "read-only" attribute for all files
- remove *.scc
- remove *.vssscc
- remove *.vspscc
- delete *.suo
- remove "SourceCodeControl..." section from your solution.sln file
- remove "SccProjectName..." section from your projects.csproj files

Answer (score 3):

I also have a hard drive with a bunch of VSS projects that I want to move to SVN projects.

Couldn't you just use [Vss2Svn](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/vss2svn)?  It sounds like this will convert VSS projects to SVN, but I have not tried it and have not heard anything about it.  Has anyone tried this to move from VSS to SVN?  Or is it better to do it manually?

Comment: I used Vss2Svn almost 2 years ago to move a critical project to Subversion.  It took a couple of test runs to get everything 'just right', but it was worth it, since it captured all of the old revision history for our project.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.poweradmin.com/sourcecode/vssmigrate.aspx

Comment: Looks like the latest version of that is hosted here: http://vssmigrate.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you could do is a clean export of all the files in the repository.  Blow away anything that is VSS.

Once you've done that then just do a subversion import and you'll be ready to go.  If you write a script you'll just have one more maintenance & failure point.  Thus my preference for just doing a clean import.

Comment: the script I am writing is to "blow away anything that is in vss" I am doing everything else manually.