# VSS to SVN migration; tool suggestions?

Tags: svn, migration, visual-sourcesafe

Anyone have good experience with tools migrating codebase from VSS to Subversion (preserving histories, meta-data)?

Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/vss2svn/wiki/RunningTheMigration) is a handy tutorial which uses [vss2svn.exe](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/vss2svn) (a tool that handles most of the VSS to SVN migration complexities for you).

Answer (score 2):

I modified the [VSS2SVN version](http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, it does history and metadata (date, author etc). Its a VB.net app with a nice GUI, that can migrate incrementally.

Comment: Cool! I am guessing it's available from Codeplex. Have you had good feedback on it? What can we expect if we go with this? Are there any gotchas or things that need manual intervention that we should be aware of?

Comment: I wrote it to fulfil my need, with a huge VSS DB. It can take a while to run (VSS's fault :) ) as it grabs everything. I would like it to group checkins to VSS at the same time as a single SVN commit, but that's just a niggle - otherwise it works fine. Try it, just read the doc on its site.

Answer (score 0):

VSS to SVN Migration using Polarion Software is very easy, useful and takes only less time. It retains all the history from VSS. Please refer http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/index.php for more details