# Migration from VSS to SVN

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe, visualsvn-server

I am using vss2svn migration tool for migrating my vss source to svn. 
I am able to migrate my vss source code and can see the history also. But I am unable to find the labels in the SVN. Can Please suggest me how I can export Labels also from VSS.

Comment: Subversion has nothing analogous to VSS's labels. What do you expect the results of "converting" your labels to look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate a Source Safe database to SubVersion with history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068567/migrate-a-source-safe-database-to-subversion-with-history)